# How to make printf of each iteration to see value in the char array word?And also what means when *a=*b(when one pointer equal to another pointer)?

Tags: c, pointers

My `printf` statements are not working. There should be like `abcdefg` for the first iteration, for the second flipping words in another direction according to code etc in the char array `word`.

```
printf("first iteration %s\n",word[1]);
printf("second iteration %s\n", word[2]);
printf("second iteration %s\n", word[3]);
printf("second iteration %s\n", word[4]);
```

Code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>


 void flipper(char *a, char *b, char *c) {  char val = *a;  *a = *b; *b
 = *c;  *c = val; }

 int main() {

    char word[] = "abcdefg";

    int i;  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {       flipper(&word[i], &word[i+1],
 &word[i+2]);   }

    return 0; }
```

Comment: void flipper(char *a, char *b, char *c) {
 char val = *a;
 *a = *b; *b = *c;
 *c = val;
}
 
int main() {
 
 char word[] = "abcdefg";
 
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  flipper(&word[i], &word[i+1], &word[i+2]);
 }
 
    return 0;
}

Comment: Can you rephrase your question (especially the first part)? I honestly do not understand it. And preferably shorten the title and put the questions into the body.

Comment: Please don't post an explanation in the title of the question, instead keep a short but descriptive title, and describe the code, what it's supposed to be doing, and what it actually does in the question body. You might want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And don't post code as a quote (with the leading `>`). Just indent all code with four spaces. See [the markdown formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help about formatting.

Comment: See the help for how to use markup. And don't put the question in the title!

Comment: Strings are arrays of characters. A character is not a string. So `%s`... `word[1]` doesn't make any sense, because %s expects a string but you give it a character. Enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*a = *b` simply means to assign the value of the object that `b` *points to* to the object that `a` *points to*. In this case, `a` points to `word[i]` and `b` points to `word[i+1]`, so `*a = *b` means that you're assigning the value of `word[i+1]` to `word[i]`.

Let's walk through the first call to `flipper`.  At the beginning of the function, the following are true:

```
Variable      Points To        Value
--------      ---------        -----
     val        n/a              'a'  // val is initialized at declaration
       a        word[0]          'a'
       b        word[1]          'b'
       c        word[2]          'c'
```

The *expression* `*a` is equivalent to the expression `word[0]`, which evaluates to the character value `'a'`.

After all the assignments have been completed, our variables now look like this:

```
Variable      Points To        Value
--------      ---------        -----
     val        n/a              'a'  // val is initialized at declaration
       a        word[0]          'b'
       b        word[1]          'c'
       c        word[2]          'a'
```

We haven't changed the values of the pointers - they still point to the same objects they did at the beginning of the function.  What we've changed are the contents of the *pointed-to* objects (`word[0]`, `word[1]`, and `word[2]`).  After the first call to `flipper`, `word` looks like this: `"bcadefg"`.

As for tracking the progress in your code, just do the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
   printf( "%d: before flip - \"%s\"", i, word ); 
   flipper(&word[i], &word[i+1], &word[i+2]); 
   printf( "%d:  after flip - \"%s\"", i, word );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, John!How can i have contact with you?

Comment: @Mangomeri: just keep asking questions here; there are plenty of smart folks to help out.  However, do read up on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), And make sure you have good reference manuals handy - my go-to reference has always been Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com).

Answer (score 0):

The `*a = *b` is pointer derenferencing, it means you're giving to the value pointed at by `a` the value pointed by `b`.

For the other part of the question I'd like some more explanation since I can't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`*a = *b;` is the same as `a[0] = b[0];`

flipper is just basically shifting 3 values : b->a, c->b, a->c

The objective of `main()` is unclear.
It basically shuffles bytes around in the table `word`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your first question fully,I think you want to print the state of the array after each iteration.For that add this line  `printf("%s",word);` after `flipper(&word[i], &word[i+1], &word[i+2]);` in for loop.

when you write `*a=*b` , it means the value at which the pointer `b` is pointing to is copied to the address at which the pointer `a` is pointing.

`*a` means value at address while `a` is just the address.